# Talend iterate on tTikaExtractor

Tags: java, row, talend, apache-tika, filelist

I'm trying to use tTikaExtractor component to extract the content of several files in a folder.

It is working with a single file but when I add a tFileList component, I don't understand how to get the content of the 2 different files.

I think it is something related to flow/iterations but I cannot manage to make it work.

For example, I have this simple job :

tFileList -(iterate)-> tTikaExtractor -(onComponentOk)-> tJava -(row1)-> tFileOutputJSON

In my java component I only have this :

```
String content = (String) globalMap.get("tTikaExtractor_1_CONTENT");
row1.content=content;
```

But in my json output I only the content of the last file and not of all files !

Can you help me on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That because you are not appending records to the output it is writing records one by one so eventually only last record is available in file.

Perhaps you can write all the rows to delimited file first then use tFileInputDelimited--main--tFileOutputJSON

to transfer all the rows.

Comment: do you mean tFileOutputDelimited ?

Comment: yes, append records to tFileOutputDelimited then use this component for input and transfer all the records to tFileOutputJSON